# How to hide passwords when typing them in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, passwords, password-protection

I am not sure wether it is the right place to ask, but the passswords are visible when I type them in Chrome. How can I change this behaviour ?

Comment: are you user or webpage developer?

Comment: It may also depends on some websites where it has an option to see password as a plain text.

Comment: Does this apply to all websites?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro yes it applies to all website

Comment: @KristoferVesi I am a user

Answer (score 0):

On the webpage which has the password text box. Right click on the password text box, select "Inspect" from the menu and there you will see an input id html tag, inside that tag make sure type is set as "password" and **not** "text".

Comment: thank you for your response. What is weird is that the input are of `password` type

Comment: you can also reverse it, when somebody leaves their password typed in, even in sites like google! :D #disclaimerDoNotDoThis